# A holiday game among friends

Tags: knowledge, seasonal

My name is Rozemarijn. I invited my friends Eleni, James, Helmut, Chiara and Pierre to participate in a fun game since we are all on Christmas holidays.

For the set up, I asked each one of them to write a message on a piece of paper, then fold it and place it in a jar. The message is composed of a couple of letters and I explained to them how to derive them. We all followed the instructions, including myself.
Then I unfolded the pieces of paper to check if everybody followed my instructions correctly.

These were the 6 messages:

- `FW`
- `ZT`
- `PK`
- `KX`
- `JN`
- `MC`

One of the messages looked a bit weird. After a quick online search, I confirmed that one of my friends did not follow my instructions correctly. What should (s)he have written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are all

> Abbreviations for how to say "Merry Christmas" around the world...

They are

> FW - Fröhliche Weihnachten (German)
>  ZT - Not sure?
>  PK - Prettige Kerst (Dutch)
>  KX - Καλά Χριστούγεννα (Greek)
>  JN - Joyeux Noël (French)
>  MC - Merry Christmas (English)

So, if we assume that everyone's name is based on a country of origin, then...

> Chiara (Italian)  should have used "BN" - “Buon Natale”

Comment: Specifically, rot13(HF Ratyvfu, fvapr n Oevg jbhyq or zber yvxryl gb fnl "Unccl Puevfgznf" be "UP")